# How to add array of strings into a property in an array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings

`[ '/nft-card', '/landing' ]`

I want this array as a property in this object array
 `[{ id: 1, name: 'NFT Preview Card', },{ id: 2, name: 'Remote Landing Page' }]`

Result should be like this

`[{ id: 1, name: 'NFT Preview Card', link: "/nft-card },{ id: 2, name: 'Remote Landing Page', link: "/landing" }]`

How to do this in javascript?

Comment: How can you tell which string is associated with which `id` or `name` value?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: both arrays are in same order, I got the answer, thanks @Nick

Comment: @IrshathCodes but they're not in the same order in your question. The string array has the landing first, and the object array has the nft preview first...

Comment: @Nick sorry mate, I posted it wrongly.

Comment: @IrshathCodes no worries, but you should probably [edit] your question so that it aligns with the accepted answer. Otherwise this won't be of much use to anyone else that finds it

Comment: yeah changed it, sorry this is the first time I'm posting in SO. Thanks for pointing it out! @Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the length of your array and your object array is equal you can use this way:

```
let array = [ '/landing', '/nft-card' ];
let objectArray = [{ id: 1, name: 'NFT Preview Card', link: "nft-card" },{ id: 2, name: 'Remote Landng Page', link: "landing" }];

  for(let i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
  objectArray[i].link = array[i];
}

console.log(objectArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both arrays are ordered correctly this can be achieved likes so.

```
const links = ['/nft-card', '/landing'] // changed the order so the result is what you want

const incompleteObjects = [{ id: 1, name: 'NFT Preview Card', },{ id: 2, name: 'Remote Landing Page' }]

const completeObjects = incompleteObjects.map((item, idx) => 
  {
    return {
      ...item,
      links: links[idx]
    }
  }
```

EDIT: adjusted `links` array order

Answer (score 0):

You can make copy of array 2. This is easy way to do:

```js
let ar1=[ '/landing', '/nft-card' ] 

let ar2=[{ id: 1, name: 'NFT Preview Card', },{ id: 2, name: 'Remote Landing Page' }]


let ar3=[]
for(let i=0;i<ar2.length;i++){
  ar2[i].line=ar1[i];
  }
  console.log(ar2)
```